# LLVM. Is it possible to set ranged labels with SwitchInst?

Tags: llvm

I know how to compile such piece of code with LLVM API (specifically with SwitchInst):

```
switch (h)
{
case 11:
   .......
case 22:
   ........
}
```

But I don't know, is it possible to compile with SwitchInst such code:

```
  Select Case x
     Case 11 To 40
        ...........
     Case 41 To 70
        ...........
  End Select
```

How to set ranged Case-Labels ?

```
switchOperator->addCase(...What I need to put here?..)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's impossible *directly* because the LLVM `switch` instruction [does not support that](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#switch-instruction):

> The ‘switch‘ instruction uses three parameters: an integer comparison
>   value ‘value‘, a default ‘label‘ destination, and an array of pairs of
>   comparison value constants and ‘label‘s. The table is not allowed to
>   contain duplicate constant entries.

Example:

```
; Implement a jump table:
switch i32 %val, label %otherwise [ i32 0, label %onzero
                                    i32 1, label %onone
                                    i32 2, label %ontwo ]
```

That said, if your ranges are not too large you can just generate many comparison values (11, 12, 13 ... 40) mapping to the same label.

Comment: Thank you. So, if my ranges may be very large, do I need to use ICmpInst instead of SwitchInst? Is it proper variant ?

Comment: @kpdev: that's a good question, and the answer is heuristical - it depends on how many cases there are and how large your ranges are. If there are just a few very large cases, then yes, a if-else chain will probably be better. But this depends on the target to, so the best thing would be to benchmark